# how to iterate through a comma-delimited column in hive?

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a hive external table data_table (id bigint, dataset string) where dataset is a comma-delimited set of integer or string values like

```
id  dataset 
1   4,3,0,6 
2   1,9,7 
3   0,8,2,7
```

My question: how can I iterate through the comma-delimited dataset values using hive?

Let's say that for when id=2 (and thus dataset=1,9,7), i want to have a looping structure that allows me to create something like:

```
when id=2,
 select val from source where x=1;
 select val from source where x=9;
 select val from source where x=7;
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In an ideal scenario, you should not have a usecase where you need to iterate on the dataset.
If you just need to access a particular element, you can do that just using the square bracket operator with an index like this myArray[index].

In other cases, explode() function from hive(as mentioned above) should help your case. Syntax:

```
SELECT id, explodeTable.dataset from data_table LATERAL VIEW explode(dataset) testTable as explodeTable
```

Make sure that you split the data_set to get an array out of it. You can use the split function for that. Syntax:

```
split(dataset,'\\,')
```

Your final query should be like this:

```
SELECT id, explodeTable.dataset from data_table LATERAL VIEW explode(split(dataset,'\\,')) testTable as explodeTable
```

Explode function only takes an array or a map as it's argument.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, dummy.x FROM baseTable
LATERAL VIEW explode(split(dataset,'\\,') dummy AS x;
```

Will give you a table like this:

```
id   x
1    4
1    3
1    0
1    6
2    1
2    9
2    7
3    0
3    8
3    7
3    2
```

Now you can:

```
select id, x
from newtable
where x in (1,9,7)
```

Comment: as with GoBrewers14 answer, when i try to implement something like this, I get a 
FAILED: ClassCastException org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.StandardListObjectInspector cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.PrimitiveObjectInspector

Comment: I made a small change that might help but See GoBrewers comment and test that the column dataset is of type string. @Ajit

Answer (score 0):

You need to split `dataset` on `,` and `explode`

```
select id, x
from (
  select id, split(dataset, '\\,') dataset_array
  from table ) A
lateral view explode(dataset_array) explodetable as x
```

not exactly sure what you want to do after that but I'll leave it to you to write the outer layer of this query.

Comment: when i try to use something like this, i get 
FAILED: ClassCastException org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.StandardListObjectInspector cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.PrimitiveObjectInspector

Comment: You get this exception when you try to `split` an `array`.  Are you sure `dataset` is of type `string` and not already an `array`?  If `dataset` is an `array`, like `[0, 4, 3, 6]` then just `explode(dataset)`, if it is a `string`, you need to `split` the `string` to make it an `array`.